# Updating Heterogeneous RecyclerView with DiffUtil - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, refresh, updates

UPDATED QUESTION:

I have a RecyclerView with Heterogenous Items (RecyclerView holding items of two view types). I want to update this RecyclerView with the new data that I receive from API.

All the examples and implementations show DiffUtil for updating RecyclerView containing items of a single view type.

I am a beginner in Android and tried the following code -

```
public class TestDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private final List<Object> oldList;
    private final List<Object> newList;

    public TestDiffCallback(List<Object> oldList, List<Object> newList) {
        this.oldList = oldList;
        this.newList= newList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        if (oldList.get(oldItemPosition) instanceof ViewType1) {
            return (((ViewType1) oldList.get(oldItemPosition)).getUniqueID())
                    .equals(((ViewType1) newList.get(newItemPosition)).getUniqueID());
        } else if (oldList.get(oldItemPosition) instanceof ViewType2) {
            return (((ViewType2) oldList.get(oldItemPosition)).getUniqueID())
                    .equals(((ViewType2) newList.get(newItemPosition)).getUniqueID());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        if (oldList.get(oldItemPosition) instanceof ViewType1) {
            final ViewType1 oldViewType1 = (ViewType1) oldList.get(oldItemPosition);
            final ViewType1 newViewType1 = (ViewType1) oldList.get(newItemPosition);

            return (
                    oldViewType1.getUniqueID().equals(newViewType1.getUniqueID())
            );
        } else if (oldList.get(oldItemPosition) instanceof ViewType2) {
            final ViewType2 oldViewType2 = (ViewType2) oldList.get(oldItemPosition);
            final ViewType2 newViewType2 = (ViewType2) oldList.get(newItemPosition);

            return (
                    oldViewType2.getUniqueID().equals(newViewType2.getUniqueID())
            );

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
    }
}
```

In my Heterogenous View Adapter I have this -

```
public void updateHomeItems(List<Object> testItems) {
    final TestDiffCallback diffCallback =
            new TestDiffCallback(this.testItems, testItems);
    final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback);

    this.testItems.clear();
    this.testItems.addAll(testItems);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

and from my Fragment Class I fetch data from API and pass it to DiffUtil as follows-

```
programAdapter.updateHomeItems(refreshedTestItemsList);
```

This is the error that I get all the time -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                     Process: com.acadnion, PID: 28315
                     io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.acadnion.models.ViewType2 cannot be cast to com.acadnion.models.ViewType1
                     at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366)
                     at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:111)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.acadnion.models.ViewType2 cannot be cast to com.acadnion.models.ViewType1
                     at com.acadnion.utils.TestDiffCallback.areItemsTheSame(TestDiffCallback.java:36)
                     at android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil.diffPartial(DiffUtil.java:224)
                     at android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffUtil.java:136)
                     at android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffUtil.java:97)
                     at com.acadnion.adapters.ProgramAdapter.updateHomeItems(ProgramAdapter.java:160)
                     at com.acadnion.fragments.TestFragment.addFetchedDataToList(TestFragment.java:182)
                     at com.acadnion.fragments.TestFragment.access$100(TestFragment.java:45)
                     at com.acadnion.fragments.TestFragment$3.onNext(TestFragment.java:153)
                     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
                     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
                     at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: so what problem you are getting with current implementation of yours ?

Comment: The question is not clear. Please clarify what is the problem that you are facing.

Comment: I wanted a RecyclerView that should have items of two types, I followed [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) and it works perfectly fine. The problem arises when I fetch new data from API and want to update my RecyclerView items. I came to know about DiffUtil and tried implementing it for updating RecyclerView with items of two different types.

Comment: First off, welcome to StackOverflow. I think you'll get more traction on this answer if you replace your specific context (StudentHomes, StudentProfiles) with something more abstract (ViewType1, ViewType2). It's hard to understand what this data actually represents.

Comment: I updated the question to be as generic as possible.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this

Comment: Unfortunately, no.